# How to get invoice_id from PayPal after success transaction

Tags: python, django, paypal

I want to get `invoice_id` that i send to PayPal.
I send to PayPal `invoice_id`:

```
...
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="MyOrderId" id="id_invoice"/>
...
```

My success url looks like this: `http://host?success=true`

I want to catch `GET` parameter `success` and edit some `Order` with `id=invoice_id`:

```
...
if request.method == 'GET':
    if request.GET.get('success'):
        order = Order.object.get(id=request.GET.get('invoice_id'))
        order.status = 'Success'
        order.save()
...
```

Maybe i need say to PayPal that i want to get returned `invoice_id` from it, or where i can find it and get?

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
request.query_params.get('field')
```

**request.query_params** this will list entire object of GET params